Python temporary directory "access is denied" error for external subprocesses on Windows
I want to create a temporary folder on windows using tempfile.TemporaryDirectory, and use subprocess to execute an external program that will use that temporary directory. This does not seem to work starting in python 3.12 (I have done most testing in 3.10 without issue, and a quick check of 3.11 showed the problem wasn't there either).
Some additional context: I'm on a corporate pc without admin rights.  I'm also using a conda environment manager and launching python from the conda prompt. I and one other person at the company are seeing this problem.
Does anyone know how I can do this on python 3.12+ on windows? Some details of the behavior and my testing follow.
Testing
Test Script
Test script executed from a conda prompt, to try and understand the problem
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    print("writing file using subprocess")
    subprocess.run("echo $null >> " + str(Path(tmpdir)/ 'subproc_test.txt'), shell=True)
    
    print("writing file using open function")
    open(Path(tmpdir)/'open_test.txt','w').write("Some text")
    
    programPause = input(f"Paused so you can inspect the tmpdir {tmpdir}.\n"
                            "Press the <ENTER> key to continue...")

Running in python 3.10
(Also quickly tested in python 3.11, behavior seems the same)
The behavior seems correct in this case. I see the following output
writing file using subprocess
writing file using open function
Paused so you can inspect the tmpdir C:\Users\cpl29573\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpe7sq8m6g.
Press the <ENTER> key to continue...

Additionally, I can navigate to the temp folder (while the python program is paused, before file deletion), and read the two created text files subproc_test.txt and open_test.txt.
Running in python 3.12
The subprocess cannot access the temporary folder, but the open function within the python process can. I see the following output. Note the Access is denied error while writing the file using the subprocess.
writing file using subprocess
Access is denied.
writing file using open function
Paused so you can inspect the tmpdir C:\Users\cpl29573\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwft8ou2y.
Press the <ENTER> key to continue...

If I try to navigate to the temporary directory in Windows file explorer, I get a pop up stating "You don't currently have permission to access this folder". I had no problem opening the folder in the python 3.10 test. If I look in the folder (using temporary admin permissions), I see that the open_test.txt file is there, but not the subproc_test.txt file.
Additional Comments

Regardless on if I run from python 3.10 or python 3.12, the folder seems to be owned by "Administrators".
Details on the "Advanced Security Settings" pop up dialog (note, I am not much of an expert on Windows security terms and settings, I'm more of a Linux guy):

On python 3.10, the temp directory is listed as inheriting
permissions from my home directory. On python 3.12, the "Inherits
from" field is blank.
On python 3.10, I'm listed as a "Principal" under permissions, but on python 3.12, the same entry is filled with "OWNER RIGHTS".



